# Discrete Mathematics: Relations

Tags: discrete-mathematics, computer-science, relations

Confused about this question: Describe two binary relations $R$ and $S$ on $\{1, 2, 3\}$ that are not equivalence relations, but whose composition $R\circ S$ is an equivalence relation.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: It's quite easy to make sure that the composition $R\circ S$ will be $\{1,2,3\}\times \{1,2,3\}$. Figure out a simple condition that ensures that, and then it should be easy to make sure none of $R$ or $S$ is an equivalence relation itself.